# Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class net.minecraft.world.item.AirItem cannot be cast to class net.minecraft.world.item.ArmorItem

Tags: java

I have been programming Minecraft Mods for 3 weeks and have a question.
I want, the variable distance is how much armor you put on.
This is my code:

```
package com.E2Z1.pickaxemod.item.custom;

import net.minecraft.world.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraft.world.entity.EquipmentSlot;
import net.minecraft.world.entity.player.Player;
import net.minecraft.world.item.ArmorItem;
import net.minecraft.world.item.ArmorMaterial;
import net.minecraft.world.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.world.level.Level;
import com.E2Z1.pickaxemod.item.ModArmorMaterial;


public class ModArmorItem extends ArmorItem {
    public ModArmorItem(ArmorMaterial material, EquipmentSlot slot, Properties settings) {
        super(material, slot, settings);
    }

    @Override
    public void inventoryTick(ItemStack stack, Level world, Entity entity, int slot,
boolean selected) {
        if(!world.isClientSide()) {
            if(entity instanceof Player) {
                Player player = (Player)entity;

                GlobalVar.distance = howmanyarmor(ModArmorMaterial.PICKAXE_ARMOR, player);

            }
        }

        super.inventoryTick(stack, world, entity, slot, selected);
    }


    private int howmanyarmor(ArmorMaterial material, Player player) {
        ArmorItem boots = ((ArmorItem)player.getInventory().getArmor(0).getItem());
        ArmorItem leggings = ((ArmorItem)player.getInventory().getArmor(1).getItem());
        ArmorItem breastplate = ((ArmorItem)player.getInventory().getArmor(2).getItem());
        ArmorItem helmet = ((ArmorItem)player.getInventory().getArmor(3).getItem());
        ItemStack boots2 = player.getInventory().getArmor(0);
        ItemStack leggings2 = player.getInventory().getArmor(1);
        ItemStack breastplate2 = player.getInventory().getArmor(2);
        ItemStack helmet2 = player.getInventory().getArmor(3);
        int numberofarmor = 0;
        if (!helmet2.isEmpty()) {
            if (helmet.getMaterial() == material){
                numberofarmor =+ 1;
            }}
        if (!breastplate2.isEmpty()) {
            if (breastplate.getMaterial() == material){
                numberofarmor =+ 1;
            }}
        if (!leggings2.isEmpty()) {
            if (leggings.getMaterial() == material){
                numberofarmor =+ 1;
            }}
        if (!boots2.isEmpty()) {
            if (boots.getMaterial() == material){
                numberofarmor =+ 1;
            }}

        return numberofarmor;
    }
}
```

When I start the world this error comes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class net.minecraft.world.item.AirItem cannot be cast to class net.minecraft.world.item.ArmorItem (net.minecraft.world.item.AirItem and net.minecraft.world.item.ArmorItem are in module minecraft@1.17.1 of loader 'TRANSFORMER' @2c8662ac)
```

Forge Version: 37.0.104
Minecraft Version: 1.17.1

(Sorry for the bad english)

I hope you can help

Comment: `getArmor(X).getItem()` returns an incompatible type so you can't cast it into an instance of `ArmorItem`.
I would recommend removing the casting and debug through the code. If you set the breakpoints correct or some prints you can get the original item type. So in general you have wrong type assumptions here. Not every item is a armor item so you need to add a instance/type check there and what to do if it is a different type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really into minecraft modding, however it seems, that you are retrieving with `getArmor`-Getters the Armor-Pieces of a Player Character. If the player does not wear any armor in a slot, I suppose, you won't receive an instance of `ArmorItem` and instead receive an `AirItem` (basically an empty slot).

Therefore, you might need to actually check for the instance type, you receive. Just the same way, you check in `public void inventoryTick` if `entity` is an instance of type `Player`.

Resulting implementation might look something like this:

```java
private int howmanyarmor(ArmorMaterial material, Player player) {
        int numberofarmor = 0;
        Item bootsItem = player.getInventory().getArmor(0).getItem();
        if (bootsItem instanceof ArmorItem) {
            ArmorItem boots = (ArmorItem)bootsItem;
            ItemStack boots2 = player.getInventory().getArmor(0);
            if (!boots2.isEmpty()) {
                if (boots.getMaterial() == material){
                    numberofarmor =+ 1;
                }}
        }
        // [... re-do for remaining slots ...]
        return numberofarmor;
    }
```